# How to convert SQL Server XML type value (xsi:nil) of DateTime to null

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a way to query SQL Server XML type so that for an element with `xsi:nil="true"`, return null instead of default datetime value, which is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`?

here is a code snippet

```
declare @data xml
set @data = 
    '<DOD   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:nil="true" />'
select  Value1 = @data.value('/DOD[1]', 'datetime'),
        Value2 = IsNull(@data.value('/DOD[1]', 'datetime'), 'NOT NULL?'),
        Value3 = nullif(@data.value('/DOD[1]', 'datetime'), '1900-01-01')
```

Value1 & Value2 both returns `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.
Is there a way to return a null, instead? without using `nullif`?

Comment: Please pay more attention to the tag prompts when asking questions. There were 6810 questions on the site tagged 'sql-server' and none tagged 'sqlserver

Comment: @Joel: Wow, great job converting sqlserver tag to sql-server.  I will be more careful there, next time.~

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "default" datetime is caused by casting an empty string which is "zero" which gives 01 jan 1900.

So: tidy the string, then CAST

```
declare @data xml

set @data = 
        '<DOD   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:nil="true" />'

select
    Value1 = CAST(NULLIF(@data.value('/DOD[1]', 'varchar(30)'), '') AS datetime)
```

Comment: I think your approach looks better than what I was trying to do, which is ------    nullif(@data.value('string(/DOD[1]/@xsi:nil="true")', 'varchar(4)'), 'true')

Comment: this worked for me - my sql datatype is datetime CAST(NULLIF(@data.value('/DOD[1]', 'datetime'), '') AS datetime)

Answer (score 1):

easy:

```
declare @data xml

set @data = 
        '<DOD   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:nil="true" />'

select
    Value1 = @data.value('(/DOD/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)')
```

Comment: I read elsewhere on SO that selecting the text() node (instead of the element node) also improves performance!  Note that selecting text() returns NULL even without xsi:nil="true"; empty elements including those with an explicit end tag also get NULL.  But... what if you wanted to supply an empty (zero-length) string?  Hm.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread has been dead for a while, but I think this way is a bit simpler:

```
SELECT value1 = NULLIF(@data.value('/DOD[1]', 'datetime'), '')
```

The string value from the xml string is evaluated first and if it's empty, will become a null datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can also explicitly check for nil like so:

```
declare @data xml

set @data = '<DOD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />'

select Value1 = @data.value('(/DOD[not(@xsi:nil eq "true")])[1]', 'datetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

This case might not be for every one

A clever way of doing this would be to remove the DOD node from the XML. So what ever node you want to be null in your result set just remove that node when adding it to the XML.

So Below will also result in a null:

```
declare @data xml

set @data = '<Test> </Test>'

select  Value1 = @data.value('(/DOD/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)')
```

It can be seen in the above example that there is no DOD node hence it will result in a null value